# What is the proper way to handle error CA1416 for .NET core builds?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Here is my C# code snippet:

```
if (Environment.IsWindows) {
   _sessionAddress = GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory();
}
...
[System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
private static string GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory() {
   ...
}
```

When I run the build, I get an error:

```
error CA1416: 'GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory()' is supported on 'windows'
```

My logic is to invoke the method only when I am on Windows. How do I turn this warning off when building on Ubuntu? Regards.

Comment: [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/code-analysis/5.0/ca1416-platform-compatibility-analyzer)  ... "*Recommended action:  check the current operating system using one of the Is<Platform> methods in the System.OperatingSystem class, for example, OperatingSystem.IsWindows(), before calling a platform-specific API.*"

Comment: Is this error referring to the server system on which the app is run, or the system of the user who is accessing the app?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a preprocessor directive to make sure that the method gets seen at compile time only in Windows:

```
#if Windows
private static string GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory() 
{
   ...
}
#endif
```

To define the directives you need to update your csproj as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsWindows Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">true</IsWindows>
    <IsOSX Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))' == 'true'">true</IsOSX>
    <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Windows</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsOSX)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>OSX</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsLinux)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>Linux</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This evaluates the OS at compile time while the question asks for evaluation at run time. Imagine e.g. that you build on Windows, but target Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, Klaus is correct. My code has to invoke Windows code when the OS is Windows and Linux logic for others.

Comment: The comment provided by JensG on the question is the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the `Environment.IsWindows` property you can apply `[SupportedOSPlatformGuard("windows")]` attribute to that property:

```
public class Environment
{
    [SupportedOSPlatformGuard("windows")]
    public bool IsWindows => OperatingSystem.IsWindows;
}
```

Then the **CA1416** analyzer would recognize the guard and would not warn within the conditional:

```
if (Environment.IsWindows) {
   _sessionAddress = GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory(); // no warning
}
```

For [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416#how-to-fix-violations)

Comment: Now, `IsWindows` is not a property it's a method; so we should call it like `OperatingSystem.IsWindows()` instead ;).

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to [`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=net-6.0) check. Next will give warning only for last clause:

```
public void M()
{
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory());
    }
    else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemoryUnix());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemoryUnix()); // warning
    }
}

[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
private static string GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemory()
{
    return "win";
}

[SupportedOSPlatform("linux")]
private static string GetSessionBusAddressFromSharedMemoryUnix()
{
    return "lin";
}
```

Comment: I get CA1416 even when using `if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))`. VS2022 + .NET 6

Comment: @tjmoore can you please share sample. code?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error by setting

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>True</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

in the project file.

and removing the local **AssembylInfo.cs** file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>True</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Comment: That ties the application to Windows. The original post is looking for a way to allow a platform check and run the platform specific code sections only on Windows and not be given the platform warning with a valid check.