# net5.0-windows: warning CA1416: 'RegistryValueKind.DWord' is supported on 'windows'

Tags: c#, .net-5

The target framework of my project is set to `net5.0-windows`.

A C# file contains a call to `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue()` which gives me the following warning:

```
warning CA1416: 'Registry.SetValue(string, string?, object, RegistryValueKind)' is supported on 'windows'
```

Why do I get this warning if my project is set to `net5.0-windows`?

Update:
[What is the proper way to handle error CA1416 for .NET core builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165941/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-error-ca1416-for-net-core-builds) as pointed out by pavel-anikhouski does not fix the problem.

Comment: [What is the proper way to handle error CA1416 for .NET core builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165941/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-error-ca1416-for-net-core-builds)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Your linked question is about how to avoid such a warning when building on Linux. This does not answer my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue arises because I use a shared AssemblyInfo.cs file in my project and have `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>` set to `false`.

Adding the following line to AssemblyInfo.cs fixes the issue:

```cs
[assembly: System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
```

The issue and workaround at GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14502